# Replace specific row-wise duplicate cells in selected columns without dropping rows

Tags: python, pandas

How can I replace specific row-wise duplicate cells in selected columns without dropping rows (preferably without looping through the rows)?

Basically, I want to keep the first value and replace the remaining duplicates in a row with NAN.

For example:

```
df_example = pd.DataFrame({'A':['a' , 'b', 'c'], 'B':['a', 'f', 'c'],'C':[1,2,3]})
df_example.head()
```

Original:

```
    A   B   C
0   a   a   1
1   b   f   2
2   c   c   3
```

Expected output:

```
    A   B   C
0   a   nan 1
1   b   f   2
2   c   nan 3
```

A bit more complicated example is as follows:

Original:

```
    A   B   C D 
0   a   1   a 1
1   b   2   f 5
2   c   3   c 3
```

Expected output:

```
    A   B   C D 
0   a   1   nan nan
1   b   2   f 5
2   c   3   nan nan
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) with [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) per rows in [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
df_example = df_example.mask(df_example.apply(lambda x: x.duplicated(), axis=1))
print (df_example)
   A    B  C
0  a  NaN  1
1  b    f  2
2  c  NaN  3
```

With new data:

```
df_example = df_example.mask(df_example.apply(lambda x: x.duplicated(), axis=1))
print (df_example)
   A  B    C    D
0  a  1  NaN  NaN
1  b  2    f  5.0
2  c  3  NaN  NaN
```